# Will running firebase init a second time overwrite node modules and cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

When I first setup my firebase project and ran firebase init I didn't think i'd host a site. So I didn't check the hosting on setup.

And so i have an ios project with the following folder structure:

```
myproject:
  - ios (xcode code)
  - firebase
        - functions
              - index.js (i have cloud functions already deployed from here)
```

If I run firebase init again can i just select "hosting" so that a public folder is added without overwriting everything in the functions folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the CLI to only initialize hosting with:

```
firebase init hosting
```

That way your other settings will remain unmodified.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. I can't remember which folder I ran the CLI from the first time ie from "myproject" which is the root folder or from within the "firebase" folder - I'm assuming it prob should be run from within the firebase folder. Cheers.

Comment: Hi @Frank. That command firebase init --only hosting isn't recognised by firebase tools and i also tried with -only but that didn't work either. I updated my firebase tools when prompted to the latest version 3.17.6. The error is : unknown option `--only'. And I made sure i'm logged in.

Comment: To confirm I just ran firebase init hosting and it worked. Cheers.

Comment: Woops. Sorry about that. Good to hear that you found it. I updated my answer.